# append spliter row after rows which contains 'REL' in action column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a split row after row which continas "REL" keyword.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    [1,'ACQ','A'],
    [2,'REL','A'],
    [3,'ACQ','B'],
    [4,'REL','B'],
    [5,'ACQ','C'],
    [6,'REL','C'],
    [7,'ACQ','A'],
    [8,'REL','A']
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','action','name'])
print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
   x action name
0  1    ACQ    A
1  2    REL    A
2  3    ACQ    B
3  4    REL    B
4  5    ACQ    C
5  6    REL    C
6  7    ACQ    A
7  8    REL    A
      x action name
0   1.0    ACQ    A
1   2.0    REL    A
2   NaN    NaN  NaN
3   3.0    ACQ    B
4   4.0    REL    B
5   NaN    NaN  NaN
6   5.0    ACQ    C
7   6.0    REL    C
8   NaN    NaN  NaN
9   7.0    ACQ    A
10  8.0    REL    A
11  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with `reindex`

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.union(df.index[df.action=='REL']+0.5))
Out[22]: 
       x action name
0.0  1.0    ACQ    A
1.0  2.0    REL    A
1.5  NaN    NaN  NaN
2.0  3.0    ACQ    B
3.0  4.0    REL    B
3.5  NaN    NaN  NaN
4.0  5.0    ACQ    C
5.0  6.0    REL    C
5.5  NaN    NaN  NaN
6.0  7.0    ACQ    A
7.0  8.0    REL    A
7.5  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Smart one the 0.5, I have a similar logic but with a few more steps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
m = df['action'].eq('REL')

(df.set_axis(df.index+m.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
   .pipe(lambda d: d.reindex(range(d.index.max()+2)))
)
```

Output:

```
      x action name
0   1.0    ACQ    A
1   2.0    REL    A
2   NaN    NaN  NaN
3   3.0    ACQ    B
4   4.0    REL    B
5   NaN    NaN  NaN
6   5.0    ACQ    C
7   6.0    REL    C
8   NaN    NaN  NaN
9   7.0    ACQ    A
10  8.0    REL    A
11  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Other option using [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
m = df['action'].eq('REL')

out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(m+1)]
out[out.index.duplicated()] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
     x action name
0  1.0    ACQ    A
1  2.0    REL    A
1  NaN    NaN  NaN
2  3.0    ACQ    B
3  4.0    REL    B
3  NaN    NaN  NaN
4  5.0    ACQ    C
5  6.0    REL    C
5  NaN    NaN  NaN
6  7.0    ACQ    A
7  8.0    REL    A
7  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract `REL` rows then mask to convert as NaN and finally concat to your original dataframe):

```
>>> (pd.concat([df, df[df['action'].eq('REL')].mask(lambda x: x == x)])
       .sort_index(ignore_index=True))

      x action name
0   1.0    ACQ    A
1   2.0    REL    A
2   NaN    NaN  NaN
3   3.0    ACQ    B
4   4.0    REL    B
5   NaN    NaN  NaN
6   5.0    ACQ    C
7   6.0    REL    C
8   NaN    NaN  NaN
9   7.0    ACQ    A
10  8.0    REL    A
11  NaN    NaN  NaN
```